# Send string via Ajax encodes space as +

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to send data to a camera, and it only accepts the data when it has no encoding to it.

The data should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventTriggerList version="2.0">
...
</EventTriggerList>
```

I have a function that creates that string just fine, and when I use it via an application to send to the camera, it works. But when I use Ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: 'PUT',   //type is any HTTP method
        contentType: "application/xml",
        data: {
            data: dataString
        },
        success: function () {
        }
    })
    ;
```

it sends the above as

```
<?xml+version="1.0"+encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventTriggerList+version="2.0">
...
</EventTriggerList>
```

and the camera won't accept it. 
I tried setting processData to false, but then my payload is only 15 bytes, instead of the expected 300 bytes of string.

How do I get the payload to be precisely as the string I generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your content type is xml and dataString is also xml, just pass it as is

```
$.ajax({
    url: target,
    type: 'PUT',   //type is any HTTP method
    contentType: "application/xml",
    data: dataString,
    success: function () {
    }
})
```